# Semantic star-rating

Tags: html

I'm implementing a star-rating system on a product page. The current one is bloated and couldn't be considered semantic.

Is there a better way to approach ratings in HTML5 now (with for e.g. the `<range>` input)? Or failing that, what is the appropriate way to write the markup for a star-rating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For voting it is semantically a form (not a set of links, because this action has side effects, so must it use POST method). Stars could be radio buttons (with `<label>`!) or submit buttons (unfortunately this will be tricky to style).

`<input type=range>` would be more appropriate if you had rating in `%` or some larger scale. For a typical 1-5 rating it might not be the best solution:

> The input element represents a control for setting the element's value to a string representing a number, but **with the caveat that the exact value is not important**, letting UAs provide a simpler interface than they do for the Number state.

For presenting the ratings, HTML doesn't have any specific elements, but you could use [hReview](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview) or [hReview-aggregate](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview-aggregate) microformats or equivalent microdata ([Google likes them](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645)).

Answer (score 3):

I think the range input looks ideal for this job. In HTML <5, I think the most semantic way to do this is via a series of radio buttons. These can be styled to look like stars and scripted to behave as one would expect rating-stars to behave.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, for a static representation of a star rating the [`<meter>`](http://html5doctor.com/measure-up-with-the-meter-tag/) element should be suitable.

> The meter element represents a scalar measurement within a known
>   range, or a fractional value; for example disk usage, the relevance of
>   a query result, or the fraction of a voting population to have
>   selected a particular candidate.